# C# how to flip a string vertically

Tags: c#, string, flip

Is it possible to flip a string vertically in C#, e.g. given

```
string s= "123456";
```

The result is:[image]

I need to assign the resulting string to a string type in C#.

The reason I need the function is that I have a chart that needs to be rotated to meet requirements. Therefore, any texts within the chart have to be rotated.

Comment: Displayed using what technology?

Comment: I can think of a couple of ways to do this with GDI

Comment: So you mean "asdf" would become "ɐspɟ"? To be quite honest, the answer to your question would probably be: yes. But I don't think that's what you're looking for. Be more specific. =)

Comment: @tf.rz thank you for your advice. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: to be honest I think @Oded has the right answer, asking him would be more suitable.

Comment: You can also rotate your display to achieve it :)

Answer (score 6):

You mean you want to render it upside down.

Strings do not have an "orientation" in and of themselves - this is entirely something to do with rendering them for display.

You can use the classes in the [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) to create an image with each character  displayed upside down (an image transform with [`RotateFlipType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rotatefliptype.aspx) for example), though whether this is a good option entirely depends on what technology you are using and how you want to display and use the text.

Comment: More a comment than an actual answer, but given the question, it's hard to blame you

Comment: I think somebody don't underst how to better help and rather disqualify the question (like you would in a panic traffic situation)..

Answer (score 3):

If you're using WPF or Silverlight, this is fairly easy.  Just apply a [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx) with a scale of `(1.0, -1.0)` to the rendered text.

Comment: +1 After the rendering assumption, that's what OP is trying to ask (I think)

Comment: problem is, OP hasn't told us what he/she is using. =(

Comment: @tf.rz: I know - I was just providing one example that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transform in WPF and rotate it in any angle

```
<RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="180" />
```

UPD: sorry, i've probably misunderstood your question.
You can use a VisualBrush to do this.

Comment: This will give a different transform than the user wishes - it will rotate around (ie, violate the "Every character remains the same position" requirement)

Comment: Right, I've misunderstood a question. I think @Pingpong can reach this effect by using WPF's VisualBrush